# SpringMVC & Spring in Action: can't redirect to home.jsp in chapter 5

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc

I'm learning SpringMVC and maven these days with the book Spring in Action but i have a question now. ***The default request to "/" should be mapped to "home.jsp" but not.*** You can also see the same question described in the book forum. 
https://forums.manning.com/posts/list/38046.page
Here are the codes:

```java
package spittr.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class SpittrWebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings(){
        return new String[]{ "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses(){
        return new Class<?>[]{ RootConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses(){
        return new Class<?>[]{ WebConfig.class };
    }
}
```

---

```
package spittr.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("spittr.web")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer){
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

---

```
 package spittr.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan.Filter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.FilterType;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"spitter"}, excludeFilters={
    @Filter(type=FilterType.ANNOTATION, value=EnableWebMvc.class)
})
public class RootConfig {

}
```

---

```
package spittr.web;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(){
        return "home";
    }
}
```

**When i run this on tomcat 7.0, it should show home.jsp. However it still shows index.jsp.**

-------------------- update -------------------------

The following test class indicates the controller class is right and this controller can response to the request "/" with home.jsp. So, where is wrong?

```
package spittr.web;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders.*;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

public class HomeControllerTest {

    @Test
    public void testHomePage() throws Exception{
        HomeController controller = new HomeController();
        MockMvc mockMvc = standaloneSetup(controller).build();
        mockMvc.perform(get("/")).andExpect(view().name("home"));   
    }
}
```

Comment: download the code from here github.com/habuma/SpringInActionExamples it works for me

Answer (score 1):

update or add in your `web.xml`

```
<welcome-file-list>home.jsp</welcome-file-list>
```

If you do not have web.xml you can generate by

> Dynamic Web Project –> RightClick –> Java EE Tools –> Generate
>   Deployment Descriptor Stub.

Also you can do [JSP redirect using JSTL libraries](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_redirect_tag.htm) in `index.jsp` to redirect to `home.jsp`

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<c:redirect url="/home.jsp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

seems to be a `path` problem.

First check your path mapping in `web.xml` file for exact url-pattern for which you are redirecting to dispatcher servlet.Assuming that you have `home.jsp` views created under

```
 /WEB-INF/views/
```

folder.

Comment: Thank you. I have home.jsp created under /WEB-INF/views/ folder. It seems that web.xml is not necessary in Servlet 3.0 environment. Can the first class in my code create and deploy dispatcherServlet automatically? I'm not clear about this interface now. If so, the default request "/" will be mapped to "/home.jsp" by using the HomeController class in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while working on Eclipse, Tomcat 9.0 on my Mac. I have spend hours to see (this small code) that where I was wrong.

However, I was able to make it run on Windows machine with Eclipse and Tomcat 8.5 and 9.0 .

I have the code hosted on GitHub at https://github.com/shortduck/ManningChapter5_SpringMVC

This is a Maven project and not Gradle. Also see the `HomeController` has the value as `value = "/home"`, this is working as well as '`/`' will work too. If you have having value as '`/`' make sure index.jsp or any other "home" page is not on the root.

My next target to find out why is this code not working on Mac.